# How can I change the style of a component based on a condition set by another component in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to create a word search application, which has a word bank below that tells the user all the words they are searching for.

```
<div className="word-bank">Your words are:
      <Word word = {totalWords[0]}></Word>
      <Word word = {totalWords[1]}></Word>
      <Word word = {totalWords[2]}></Word>
      <Word word = {totalWords[3]}></Word>
      <Word word = {totalWords[4]}></Word>
      <Word word = {totalWords[5]}></Word>
</div>
```

Each letter on the board is a component that will be highlighted if it is clicked. The variable emptyWord is declared as a blank string and being imported from a separate helper JS file.

```
function Letter(props) {
  const [isPicking, setIsPicking] = useState(false);


  const handleClick = () => {
    setIsPicking((current) => !current);
    emptyWord = checkWord(props.letter,emptyWord);

  };

  return (
    <th
      style={{ backgroundColor: isPicking ? "green" : "" }}
      className="letter"
      onClick={handleClick}
    >
      {props.letter}
    </th>
  );
}
```

When the letters are clicked, it calls the function `checkWord()` which combines the letters selected and checks if it is a valid word. This function is being imported from a js file with helper functions.

```
export const checkWord = (letter, emptyWord) => {
  emptyWord = emptyWord.concat(letter.toLowerCase());

  debugger;
  for (let i = 0; i < wordsArr.length; i++) {
    if (wordsArr[i] === emptyWord) {
      console.log(totalWords);
    }
  }
  return emptyWord;
};
```

My goal is to update the CSS of each word in the word bank to signify that the word was indeed found by the user. I.e. putting a slash through the word.

There is probably a much simpler way to do this that I can't see, so if you see one, please tell me.

Comment: is it because of mutating the prop here `emptyWord = emptyWord.concat(letter.toLowerCase());` 

Comment: This is only setting the letters to lowercase because the array that they are being compared to is  also in lowercase. The word bank is not affected by this.

Comment: What is this `emptyword` variable? You haven't showed where this variable is declared, or how it is shared amongst the letter components. Are you just exporting it from a module?